# Delete rows from table, except specified number (limit number of rows)

Tags: mysql, sql

How to delete all rows from the MYSQL table (2 million of rows), keeping eg. latest 100.

The query to select what I want to keep would be:

```
 SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 100;
```

So I need a query which deletes all rows except selected in this query. Spedyfying a list of IDs using `where in` seems like an overkill.

Comment: What's about to insert the 100 rows into temp table, truncate the table where you are deleting from, then insert those 100 rows back into the main table.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date < (SELECT date FROM mytable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100,1)`

try that

It should delete all records but the last 100 entries based on the `date` column

*edit:* typos

Comment: You have a typo with the `1),100`. Also you assume that ID is in order by date - it might not be.

Comment: That doesn't look right - that does offset 100, rowcount 1.

Comment: @Ariel: OP wants top 100 recs intact and delete the rest. And hence offset is set.

Comment: DOH! Yes, you are correct, I misunderstood your query, have an upvote.

Comment: Possible bug: If the date is not unique it might save more than 100 rows, if the date on the 100th row is duplicated. Probably doesn't matter for this.

Comment: @Ariel: If rows 90-110 has the exact same date value, it will cut the last 10. Since the query keeps the first 100 rows ordered by the date value, non-unique date values shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: @Caweren I don't understand what you mean. I'm pretty sure if 90-110 were duplicate dates then at there will be 110 rows in the table, not 100. (Or 90 if you used `<=` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this :

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared statement. 
I tested on MySQL and it works.

```
PREPARE row_del FROM 'DELETE FROM mytable LIMIT ?'
; 

SELECT @row_num := count(*) - 100
FROM mytable
;

EXECUTE row_del USING @row_num
;
```