# How to delete duplicate rows based on a column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have certain geocoded addresses that are duplicates in my SQL table I am trying to delete and only leave one. I've written the code below:

```
SELECT
address`, COUNT(*)
FROM stores
GROUP BY  address`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

However, it only shows the address and the actual count (which is 2) showing duplicates and won't let me select any to delete. What additional sql command do I need to add to delete duplicates?

Comment: This post is talking about removing duplicate rows in SQL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete rows from table, except specified number (limit number of rows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527833/delete-rows-from-table-except-specified-number-limit-number-of-rows)

Comment: You can use a LIMIT clause in DELETE statements; depending on how you are going to execute the DELETEs you could just construction them with a limit of the retrieved count - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is unique column in your table `stores`

```
   DELETE FROM stores WHERE id NOT IN 
    ( SELECT min FROM (SELECT MIN(id) AS min FROM stores GROUP BY address) AS T1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like no rows were deleted. Can you explain the T1?

Comment: @chronotrigga there was a mistake in query. its corrected. Check it now. T1 is used to avoid the error 1093 of mysql. Because we cannot use target table for delete.